# Why is it safer to not short left and right audio jack outputs together?

Tags: audio

I've read that the best way to "mix" two left and right line-level stereo jack outputs is to first connect each to a 1k resistor and then to your mono input.

Why is this preferred over just shorting them directly together and then connecting them to a single input?

Comment: To prevent exceeding current draw.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Surely the output voltages will both be at, say, 3V, and not make much difference to the input drawing the current as the voltages are in parallel and do not sum together?

Comment: Think: If the output voltages were the same how would you have stereo sound?

Comment: @GaryAllen what if you play drums on left channel and piano on right channel? Or a sine wave on left, and antiphase sine wave on right? Completely different signals, and only output impedance and difference of voltages set the current that flows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line-level outputs expect a high impedance load, so the output transistors typically don't have very strong current capabilities.

The whole point of stereo is that both channels are not always the same, so it's not inconceivable that, for instance, at some point the left channel is at -1V while the right channel is simultaneously at +1V.

Now the output is effectively shorted. In the worst case, this can fry your output transistors.

The difference doesn't have to be 2V like in this example, for excessive current to flow. In principle, *any* difference in output voltage between the left and right channel will create a shortcut condition.

Even if it doesn't damage the output transistors, this will affect the sound quality, and probably not for the better. If you mix the channels together with resistors, the resistors will effectively create a voltage divider, and the signals will be mixed in a controlled (or at least predictable) way. Without resistors, whatever output transistor is "strongest" will "win", and the signal will be mixed in an arbitrarily lopsided manner.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is same as not connecting any other outputs together.

When connecting two outputs together, outputs can try to drive the outputs to different voltages. Since they both can use considerable amount of current to try to set the output voltage to certain potential, shorting two outputs together can cause a significant amount of current to flow from one output into another output.

To avoid shorting two outputs together, so that there is no large short circuit current, resistors are used to limit the current and take average of the two different voltages.