# Why can you simply short a line-level output to ground?

Tags: audio

I've read that one of the ways to sum two line-level outputs into mono is to simply ignore the right channel and connect the left channel to the mono input.

In doing so, it has been said that you can (and should?) simply short the other right channel to ground.

Why does this not cause interference / heating effects? Is it really safe to do this? (of course there are probably better ways but this seems like a simple "quick and easy" way)

Comment: Then you just get half stereo mono. Not an effective way. Use resistors to sum L and R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's so closely related to the one posted minutes earlier by the OP, that they could have been combined? [Why is it safer to not short left and right audio jack outputs together?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530309/why-is-it-safer-to-not-short-left-and-right-audio-jack-outputs-together). Take note that this isn't a forum and you are pushing questions down the queue.

Comment: Why ground it? Some devices can heat and break. Why not simply leave unused channel disconnected?

Comment: "it has been said" by who?

Comment: Sorry - I thought the questions were similar but on different specific topics, so I separated. But obviously I was misinformed regarding this question. I've closed it.

Answer (score 0):

It does cause heating effects. Usually a very small one, because line level is not the same as a power amplifier, but the energy has to go somewhere. Usually it's dissipated at the driver.

Many modern line drivers will be able to detect that this has happened and shut down or power-limit their outputs.